# IAM PassRole restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need the permissions to pass an execution role to a Lambda when I create a CF.
So I have given the role used for creating the CF this:

```
Effect: Allow
Action:
  - iam:PassRole
Resource:
  - "myexecutionrole"
```

So now my CF role can pass the execution role to any resource. I want to restrict this. I want it only to be able to pass the role to the Lambda function it is for. So I have been looking into policy conditions, put here I only find solution for restricting the source of the call not the target.
Is that I want possible and how?

Comment: How would you know the function name/arn before you run your cloudformation template which creates it?

Comment: I know how the arn is build. So i know how the name will be. I know that I cant have it referenced due to cirkel dependencies. But if I just predict the arn it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So what is the problem? Did you try anything? Can you actually show full IAM role and provide any errors you get?

Comment: The issue is that I cant find a good condition key to do the restriction I am after. I want a key the is not checking the caller of the api call but checking the target for it.

Comment: What about `iam:AssociatedResourceArn`?

Comment: This looks promising, I will test it out.

Comment: You suggestion worked. If you want you can add it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `iam:AssociatedResourceArn`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html):

> Specifies the ARN of the **resource to which this role will be associated** at the destination service.